# How can I make my checkbox appear and disappear?

Tags: jquery

I have the following CSS and HTML:

```
<select id="ContentID" name="ContentID">
   <option selected="selected" value="00">Menu</option>
   <option value="01">Topic</option>
</select>
<input id="htmlEdit" type="checkbox" />

$("#ContentID")
.val($.cookie("ContentID_dropdown"))
.change(function () {
   $.cookie("ContentID_dropdown", $(this).val(), { expires: 365, path: '/' });
});
```

Is there a way that I can make the checkbox be visible if the "Menu" is selected and not visible if
anything else is selected? I am not sure how to do this. I guess I need something that will take into account that the value could be one or other based on the cookie and then the user could go in and change it.

Comment: +1 I like how this script make it look very easy to save the state of something, a possible optimization is to write a jQuery plugin which combines your two cookie lines into `.save("ContentID_dropdown", 365)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to check the value and respond accordingly

```
$("#ContentID")
.val($.cookie("ContentID_dropdown"))
.change(function () {
   if($(this).val() == "00")
      $("#htmlEdit").hide();
   else
      $("#htmlEdit").show();
   $.cookie("ContentID_dropdown", $(this).val(), { expires: 365, path: '/' });
});
```

Comment: +1 for you too because I kept improving my code within the edit time, my final version combines embedding it in the existing script and a comment that was on another answer that now seems to have been deleted.

Comment: Thanks :) I'm a bit slow with the typing haha

Comment: @Developer - Sorry for slow reply. When I try this code I get the error: SCRIPT5009: '$this' is undefined - update. Just noticed and changed it to $(this).

Answer (score 2):

You need to look whether another option has been selected, something like:

```
$("#ContentID")
.val($.cookie("ContentID_dropdown"))
.change(function () {
    $.cookie("ContentID_dropdown", $(this).val(), { expires: 365, path: '/' });
    $("#htmlEdit").toggle($(this).val() == "00");
});
```